# Hiding a method from YARD (the right way)

Tags: ruby, yard

I am using [YARD](http://yardoc.org) to document one of my Ruby projects. I have certain methods that I do not want to be included in the documentation, things like `#inspect` and `#to_s` that you expect to exist and return a reasonable result.

It is possible to hide these methods using the `@private` tag and the `yardoc --no-private` command-line option:

```
# @private let's not document this
def inspect; ...; end
```

However, the [YARD documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#private) on `@private` explicitly states:

> *Note: This method is not recommended for hiding undocumented or “unimportant” methods. This tag should only be used to mark objects private when Ruby visibility rules cannot do so.*

If I use `@api private` instead, YARD (nicely) tags the methods with a [private](/questions/tagged/private) badge in the documentation, but still shows them.

Is there a "legal" way to hide methods from YARD output?

Comment: From the website: "Although YARD is mostly compatible with RDoc, it does not support RDoc "directives" such as :stopdoc: or :nodoc:. There are a few reasons for this, but the most important is that it is very easy to misuse :nodoc:, and this misuse often causes your readers to miss out on vital information in your documentation." I believe what you want to do is intentionally not possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my limited tests, I noticed the following works well (and **doesn't** have the explicit note in the documentation to avoid for your use case):

```
# @!visibility private
def inspect; ...; end
```

According to the [yard documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#visibility):

> @!visibility public | protected | private
>
> Modifies the current parsing visibility (public, protected, or private).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the same as labeling every member `@private`, so the same note applies. The author of Yard simply doesn’t like the idea of changing visibility in documentation because he considers it to be misused.